# JS redirect user to different page if the current url contains .

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with software that does not allow me to directly make edits to some pages. I would like to redirect viewers to a different URL if the page they are viewing contains a certain string.

This is what I have tried but it seems to redirect you to the new location no matter what page of the site you are on.

```
<script>
var EDITURL = window.location.href;
if ('url:contains("testthis")') {
window.location.replace("http://www.test.com");
};
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this will work window.location.href="http://www.test.com".

Comment: `'url:contains("testthis")'` – that is not a condition, it is just a simple text literal … and as it is not empty, it is always true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, `'url:contains("testthis")'` is viewed as a string and is [truthy](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/).

```
if('your text'){
  // code here will always be executed.
}
```

This code should work:

```
<script>
    if(document.location.href.indexOf('testthis') > -1) { 
        // indexOf will return the position of the first occurence of this string in the url
        // or -1 it it's not there.
        document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
   var fullUrlLink = location.href;

   if (fullUrlLink.search("/yourelement/") >= 0) {
       window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
   } else {
       window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
   }
```

Comment: location.href.search is exactly what I needed. +1

Answer (score 1):

As i see it:

```
if(EDITURL.indexOf('testthis') > -1) { ... }
```

Or the same less readable:

```
if(~EDITURL.indexOf('testthis')) { ... }
```